# How to escape Special character in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have XML data in string and tried to convert that string in to XML using

```
XmlDocument xl=new XmlDocument();
xl.LoadXml(mystring);
```

It was not parsing because my string has special character in XML element like below.

```
<ROOT>
 <SUB>
   <DATA>name < lastname</DATA>
   <DATA>Myname > lastname</DATA>
   <DATA>some special character in between text</DATA>
    ......
    .....
 </ROOT>
</SUB>
```

There were many `<DATA>` in my XML. It was generating dynamically.

I have tried to change `< &lt; > &gt;` but it was replacing other XML tags. How to escape above special characters without change other XML tags?

Comment: Well, it's not valid XML to begin with. Are they expecting you to handle this tag soup? The end tags are the wrong way round too. It would be best to correct the problem at its source: whatever creates the XML in the first place, rather than trying to figure out what was meant.

Answer (score -1):

Use below strings in XML

```
   &lt; ==>  lesser-than = <
   &gt; ==> greater-than = >
```